# Where the local sqlite database information is saved in Android OS for Mobile Web Applications?

Tags: android, sqlite, web

How can we save remote database (let us say SQL Server database) for some tables in local sqlite android client from android mobile web application (Browser). Where the local sqlite database information is saved in Android OS for Mobile Web Applications?. I already know how the sqlite information is saved for native mobile application for Android. I know we can use content providers to access browser history etc information. But I would like to know where the information is saved if we save in the form of sqlite of remote sqlserver database information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application creates an database this database is saved in the directory `"DATA/data/APP_NAME/databases/FILENAME"`. `"DATA"` is the path which `Environment.getDataDirectory()` returns, `"APP_NAME"` is your application name and `"FILENAME"` is the name you give the database during creation. `Environment.getDataDirectory()` usually return the SD card as location.